# Magento admin - Customer Edit page no longer working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I attempt to edit a customer using the Magento backend administration I get the following errors in the console.log and the latter section of the page never loads.

The screenshot illustrates how it appears (note the header is loading but nothing after this) 
http://postimg.org/image/kewhh988l/

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.mydevsite.com.192.168.0.155.xip.io/index.php/admin/customer/edit/id/36067/key/24163240a85bbe65bb54b2f5b7fda0bf/

ReferenceError: _cp_integrate is not defined

if (!_cp_integrate) return;
f347ed...1554.js (line 22806)
TypeError: this.blockMsg is null

this.blockMsgError              = this.blockMsg.select('.error-msg')[0];
```

-- UPDATE -- 
As requested here is my customer.xml

```
<layout>
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit" name="customer_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="optional_zip_countries" as="optional_zip_countries" template="directory/js/optional_zip_countries.phtml" />
        <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/product/composite/configure.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>varien/configurable.js</file></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="customer/tab/view.phtml">
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
            </block>
            <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" template="customer/edit/js.phtml" name="customer.edit.js" as="customer_edit_js"></block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
<adminhtml_customer_group_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_group" name="customer_group"></block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_group_index>
<adminhtml_customer_wishlist>
    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist.edit.tab" output="toHtml" />
</adminhtml_customer_wishlist>

<adminhtml_customer_orders>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_orders" name="adminhtml.customer.edit.tab.orders"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_orders>

<adminhtml_customer_carts>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_carts" name="admin.customer.carts"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_carts>

<adminhtml_customer_viewcart>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_cart" name="admin.customer.view.cart"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_viewcart>

<adminhtml_customer_viewwishlist>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_wishlist" name="admin.customer.view.wishlist"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_viewwishlist>

<adminhtml_customer_lastorders>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_orders" name="admin.customer.lastorders"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_lastorders>

<adminhtml_customer_productreviews>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_reviews" name="admin.customer.reviews"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_productreviews>

<adminhtml_customer_producttags>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_tag" name="admin.customer.tags"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_producttags>

<adminhtml_customer_taggrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_tag" name="admin.customer.tags"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_taggrid>

<adminhtml_customer_newsletter>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter_grid" name="admin.customer.newsletter.grid"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_newsletter>

<adminhtml_customer_grid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_grid" name="admin.customer.grid"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_grid>

<adminhtml_customer_cart>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_cart" name="admin.customer.view.edit.cart" />
    </block>
</adminhtml_customer_cart>
```

-- UPDATE --
When I remove the following block from layout file above I am no longer getting the stated error messages within the console.log - and the page is rendering more of the page.

Now I can see the following - the username is visible as are the other buttons on the right hand side such as Customer Edit etc...

So unless I am totally off the mark with this.. it is related to the following block that I just commented out

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
        <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="customer/tab/view.phtml">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
        </block>
            <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

http://postimg.org/image/n8vyjpiwl/

-- UPDATE --
Getting really close now! I have commented out the following code in one of the core files:

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tabs.php
```

Code at line 92-97

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('newsletter/subscriber')) {
    $this->addTab('newsletter', array(
       'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Newsletter'),
       'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter')->initForm()->toHtml()
    ));
}
```

Once this code is commented out - the page renders as expected - so it is CERTAINLY related to something within this chunk of code. It is something wrong with what is contained within the 'content' within the array above. I'll post that view shortly.

-- UPDATE -- 
As already stated above the problem is 100% caused by the following line above

```
'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter')->initForm()->toHtml()
```

Below is the code from that Admin Block :

```
/**
 * Customer account form block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Newsletter extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('customer/tab/newsletter.phtml');
}

public function initForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('_newsletter');
    $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
    $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    Mage::register('subscriber', $subscriber);

    if ($customer->getWebsiteId() == 0) {
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Newsletter Information')));

    $fieldset->addField('subscription', 'checkbox',
         array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Subscribed to Newsletter?'),
                'name'  => 'subscription'
         )
    );

    if ($customer->isReadonly()) {
        $form->getElement('subscription')->setReadonly(true, true);
    }

    $form->getElement('subscription')->setIsChecked($subscriber->isSubscribed());

    if($changedDate = $this->getStatusChangedDate()) {
         $fieldset->addField('change_status_date', 'label',
             array(
                    'label' => $subscriber->isSubscribed() ? Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Date Subscribed') : Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Date Unsubscribed'),
                    'value' => $changedDate,
                    'bold'  => true
             )
        );
    }

    $this->setForm($form);
    return $this;
}

public function getStatusChangedDate()
{
    $subscriber = Mage::registry('subscriber');
    if($subscriber->getChangeStatusAt()) {
        return $this->formatDate(
            $subscriber->getChangeStatusAt(),
            Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true
        );
    }

    return null;
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild('grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter_grid','newsletter.grid')
    );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

}
```

Comment: can you place your customer.xml from app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\customer.xml ?

Comment: @KeyurShah I've added the customer.xml above in my original post

Comment: Check to see if a module from local or community isn't overriding the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Newsletter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated here is what I would try to do..

- Check the error logs for apache/nginx and scroll to the bottom to find the most recent errors, this error log may be massive depending on how old it is. You might want to delete it and then let apache recreate it when it triggers the error and writes to the log file.
- Magento can be problematic with sessions and caching. Logout of any admin/customer sessions in Magento, empty ALL caches in the administration.
- Empty all browsers sessions/caches etc.. I'd even possibly use a different browser too
- View the console.log and use the stack trace option this will highlight the route it is taking useful when seeing what javascript is being called etc..
- In the view/file you mentioned, comment out a line or a block out at a time, and run the page again and see what happens. This can help you narrow down the 'problem code'.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You got 500 Internal Server Error, so there are 3 places need to check:

1. Check your apache/nginx log to see error message
2. Check var/report folder
3. In browser, view page source and scroll to bottom.